# Vector of new vectors

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose I have a vector of dynamically allocated vectors, something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>*> map;
```

Do i have to deallocate each of the vectors inside map manually or are they deallocated automatically by the vector destructor itself?
If I have to do it manually is this a good way to go:

```
for(auto& t : map) delete[] t;
```

?

Comment: yes each time you use "new "you must have one associated "delete", that's the rule.

Comment: A good way is to have a vector of vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` instead. Or, even better, if you know the sizes, to map elements to a 1D vector (this would be most efficient). If you insist on a vector of pointers, then use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<double>>>`. But, a pointer to a vector rarely makes sense.

Comment: C++ **never** deallocates a pointer automatically. If C++ had such a rule then it would also have to keep track of each pointer to know whether is had been allocated in the first place and whether it is safe to deallocate now (i.e. there are no copies of the pointer elsewhere). That would impose a huge run time burden on a C++ program. There are languages like that but not C++. In C++ you manage the memory or, better still, get library code to do it for you.

Comment: *"I have a vector of dynamically allocated vectors"*.... why? why not just a vector of vectors? what do you think is the added value of having dynamically allocated vectors? Internally the data is dynamically allocated anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to free them with `delete` not `delete []` because a vector is not an array.

But I wouldn't see any reason why you wouldn't use

`std::vector<std::vector<double>>`

This way you wouldn't need to worry about the allocation of the vector

Comment: I used dynamic vectors, because i pass each of those dynamic vectors to a thread to push_back new elements, and doing it by dynamic allocation gave a speed boost. But as I tried to use delete[] on those dynamic vectors I had some errors. As suggested by @DanielLangr I replace the dynamic vectors by smart pointers, this should be a safer way.

Comment: But thanks for the answer, now I know to always delete[] new allocated objects

Answer (score 0):

> Do i have to deallocate each of the vectors inside map manually or are they deallocated automatically

If you allocate manually, then you must deallocate manually (unless you transfer ownership to a smart pointer in which case you preferably should not have allocated manually in the first place).

Allocating vectors manually is not a good way.